# UIBarButtonItem action fails with unrecognised selector

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibarbuttonitem, unrecognized-selector

I have searched around a lot but couldn't find a solution to my problem. I have a function that I want to call as a selector when one of the UIBarButtonItem is tapped. My UIViewController is embedded in a Navigation Controller.

**In .h file**

```
- (IBAction)EventsAction:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
```

**In my .m file I create my UIBarButtonItems in the viewDidLoad method**

```
UIBarButtonItem *composer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose target:self action:@selector(EventActions:)];
composer.tag = 0;

UIBarButtonItem *notifList = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"!N!" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(EventActions:)];
notifList.tag = 1;

NSArray *buttonArr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:composer, notifList, nil];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = buttonArr;
```

**And the function is defined as:**

```
- (IBAction)EventsAction:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"connection"]) {
    if (sender.tag == 0) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"newEvent" sender:self];
    }
    if (sender.tag == 1) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"notificationView" sender:self];
    }
}

else {
    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"NoConnectionTitle", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"NoConnection", nil) delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Tamam", nil) otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [myAlert show];
}
```

}

However when I run this code and tap one of the buttons I get the unrecognized selector error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BIAllEventsController EventActions:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ddc1400'

I have also tried to change the IBAction to void, but did not solve my problem either.

**EDIT**

Thank you everyone and sorry for the silly mistake. Though it teaches very important lessons such as:

- Never trust auto-complete
- A good night sleep won't solve every problem

Comment: This is because the selector `EventActions:` is not recognized. Have a closer look at its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misspell in the code, your method's name is `EventsAction` with a **s**, but in this line

```
UIBarButtonItem *composer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose target:self action:@selector(EventActions:)];
```

you are using `EventActions` without the **s**. You have to change your method declaration of the initialization of the `UIBarButtonItem`s.

Answer (score 0):

Because you method name is `EventsAction` but you are adding `EventActions` (s is misplaced) as selector of your `barButton`.